# Getting the first 5 lines from PID and COMMAND using top

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

hi i'm struggling to figure out how to get the top 5 lines of the PID and COMMAND headers when opening top

at the moment im using

`top | awk '{print $1,$2}NR==5{exit}'`

this is obviously annoyingly giving me this:

```
Processes: 390
2021/12/17 13:47:48
Load Avg:
CPU usage:
SharedLibs: 146M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following code. Since you need top 5 PIDs details so printing first 5 lines wouldn't work here. So skipping first 6 lines in output of top(which are about system details).

```
top -b | awk 'FNR>=7 && FNR<=12{print $1};FNR==12{exit}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation of above code would be, passing `top` command's output to `awk` as an standard input. Then in `awk` program checking condition if line number is from 7th to 12th then print it and on 12th line exit out of program.

Where definition of `top -b` option is as follows from `man top`:

> b  :Batch-mode operation Starts top in Batch mode, which could be
> useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.  In
> this mode, top will  not  accept  input and runs until the iterations
> limit you've set with the `-n' command-line option or until killed.

Comment: the result i'm getting is including other data fields and not just PID and COMMAND. how would i modify this to just show those 2 fields

Comment: @Alex, Ok, please try `top -b | awk 'FNR>=7 && FNR<=12{print $1};FNR==12{exit}'` code once and let me know if this goes well?

Comment: works excellently after modifying the print to include $12. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Other Solutions:**

top -b for batch mode
top -n 1 for a single shot (no loop)

Getting lines

- with --> head -12 | tail -6
- or   --> awk 'FNR>=7 && FNR<=12'
- or   --> sed -n 7,12p

Print PID and Command

- awk '{print $1, $NF}'

...

```
top -b|head -12|tail -6|awk '{print $1, $NF}'
top -b -n 1|awk 'FNR>=7 && FNR<=12{print $1, $NF}'
top -b -n 1|sed -n 7,12p|awk '{print $1, $NF}'
```

Comment: What does this do that isn't covered by the accepted answer? Can you [edit] your answer to offer more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For MAC OS X, the command is:

```
top -a -n20 | awk 'FNR>=11 && FNR<=31{print $0};FNR==31{exit}' > cpustat.txt
```